# Run a raspberry pi discord bot written in C# on linux?

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, discord

As the title says, I'm making a discord bot written in C# and I recently got a raspberry pie and wondering if I could install Linux on it and then run the bot on it even though it's written in c#?

Comment: maybe, look in to .NET Core though.  https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxredhat

Comment: Google "C# on raspberry pi"

Comment: Yes it is completely doable. You will need to target your c# project to .NET Standard or [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs201

Comment: @MaxCheetham Alright! Will give it a shot and update the thread if i get it working ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise that I'm answering over a year late, but as this is the first Google result, I thought it would be helpful to write a quick guide here.

This will run the **.NET Core 2.1** Discord Bot app on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

Also, this is under the assumption that you don't have a monitor available for your Pi (like me).

Firstly, publish your .NET Core app to run on ARM. Using `WIN+X` then `C` open command prompt. Type

`cd <Path to project>`

This should be the path to the folder containing the .sln Visual Studio file. Do not include the .sln file in the command.

Next, run `dotnet publish -r linux-arm`, this may take a while but should eventually output the directory that it has compiled to. Note this directory down somewhere, because you'll need it later.

Now, you'll need to install PuTTY on your Windows machine. This is a tool we will use to temporarily connect to the Raspberry Pi. Download it [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

To enable PuTTY to work, take the SD Card out of your Raspberry Pi and put it into your computer. In the BOOT drive, create a file called "ssh" with no extension. It must be in the root directory of the drive.

Now put the SD Card back in the Pi and turn it on. Ensure it is connected to the internet.

Once you have installed PuTTY, run the program and there will be a "Host name (or IP address)" box. Find the IP of your Raspberry Pi by looking on your router's setting page, or, if you have a monitor, by running `ifconfig` on the Pi's command line interface. Enter this IP Address into the box and ensure that connection type "SSH" is selected. Click Open or press enter.

A console window should appear, prompting you to log in. Use the credentials you have set up on the Pi. If you have not changed these, the default username is `pi` and the password `raspberry`.

Next, run these commands in PuTTY in this order to install .net:

`sudo apt-get -y update`

`sudo apt-get -y install libunwind8 gettext`

`wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.300-rc1-008673/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-rc1-008673-linux-arm.tar.gz`

`wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/2.1.0-rc1-final/aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0-rc1-final-linux-arm.tar.gz`

`sudo mkdir /opt/dotnet`

`sudo tar -xvf dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-rc1-008673-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/`

`sudo tar -xvf aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0-rc1-final-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/`

`sudo ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin`

To ensure these have all worked, run `dotnet --info`. You should get lots of information about the .NET Core installation.

Now you must download a tool to move files from a directory on the computer to the Pi.
Download pscp.exe [here](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/pscp.exe). Note the location you have downloaded it to.

Open command prompt again, and type `cd <Location of pscp.exe>`, not including pscp.exe itself in the command.

Now, run this command in command prompt to move the compiled files to the Pi.

`PSCP -r "<Path to linux-arm folder>" pi@<Pi's IP Address>:/home/pi/`

Ensure the `"`s are there, because otherwise the program will become confused if there are spaces in your file path.

Now, in PuTTY, navigate to where the file we want to run is. This will be a file with the same name as your solution (.sln) and should be located in `linux-arm/publish/`. Use `cd <path to file>` in PuTTY. (Do not include the file itself in the command). If you ever want to see all the files and folders in the directory you are currently in, use `ls -la`

To prepare your program to be run, run this in PuTTY: `chmod 777 ./"<File Name>"`

Finally, the program can be run. Use `./"<File Name>"` to run it. This will run the program only if the PuTTY window is open, but it is good to test it now and have the satisfaction of all that hard work paying off.

To make the program continue to run when the PuTTY window is closed, you must install yet more stuff. (Use `CTRL+C` to close the currently running program) Run, in PuTTY, `sudo apt-get install screen`, then run the following command to start your bot:

`screen -dmS discordbot "/home/pi/linux-arm/publish/<File Name>"`

The bot should now run without the PuTTY window being open.

You can make the bot start automatically on reboot by using crontab. Run `crontab -e` to edit it. You can add a line at the bottom which begins with @reboot followed by commands. Seperate each command with ;.

An example crontab:

```
@reboot cd "FileBot/Running Environment" ; screen -dmS filebot "/home/pi/FileBot/Files/publish/FileBot"
```

You can then use `sudo reboot` to test this.

Hope this helps! If you have any issues following these instructions, please contact me or my friend on Discord (230Daniel#1920 or ComputerNerd100#0001) or comment on this answer.

Comment: Just now logged in and marked your respond as a answer so you get cred :) Thanks for the help doe!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is generally yes(look into Mono posted link below). There may be some functionality which might not be supported by standard functionality is. I have used it and I know it works

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/

Comment: Ah alright! I will check it out and install ubuntu on it but there is 2 different on the RBP website? Which one would i use?
Ubuntu Mate or Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Comment: most likely doesn't matter, may be mono project site will help. As mono libs will be downloaded and installed on the system